# Django: How to make admin not delete the relative objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When deleting an object in admin interface, I want to prevent removal of related objects.

```
class ObjectToDelete(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

class RelatedObject(models.Model):
    otd = models.ForeignKey('app.ObjectToDelete', null=True, blank=True)
```

Since the `ForeignKey` in `RelatedObject` is nullable, I should be able to set it to `None` instead of deleting the whole object. And this is exactly the behaviour I want to have.

I know that I can create custom delete actions for this admin interface.

And I am also aware that I could make `ManyToManyField` in `ObjectToDelete` which would also prevent removal of `RelatedObject`. But then I wouldn't have the one-to-many relation which I want.

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) option for your foreign key. If you you want to set the value to `None` when the related object is deleted, use `SET_NULL`:

```
models.ForeignKey('app.ObjectToDelete', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

These rules apply however you delete an object, whether you do it in the admin panel or working directly with the Model instance. (But it won't take effect if you work directly with the underlying database in SQL.)

Comment: It might be better to use [`SET_NULL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL) for your example instead of `CASCADE`, since the OP doesn't want the related object to be deleted.

Comment: @Alasdair, yes you are right we can use SET_NULL here. But in terms of performance both are at the database level, can't say for sure who is faster.

Comment: It's not about which is faster. Using `models.CASCADE` (the default behaviour until Django 2.0) deletes the related objects. That's exactly what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Alasdair please edit the answer, indicating that `SET_NULL` is what I wanted. So I can accept it. Thanks